# Getting NoClassDefFoundError with custom handler on Glassfish 3.1

Tags: classloader, glassfish-3, urlclassloader

### The problem

1. Our web app creates a `java.net.URL` passing our custom implementation of a `URLStreamHandler` to the constructor.
2. On that URL, we call `url.openConnection()`.
3. The `java.net.URL` code calls `openConnection()` on our handler.
4. At this point, we get a `NoClassDefFoundError` for a class used by the handler.

This happens with Glassfish 3.1, but doesn't happen with Tomcat, WebLogic, and JBoss. (Also, it used to work on older versions of Glassfish.)

### What I tried

I tried adding a [`glassfish-web.xml`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beaql.html) to tell Glassfish to load classes first from the web app (as expected), but this doen't solve the problem.

```
<glassfish-web-app>
    <class-loader delegate="false"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

How can I solve this problem, and why is this happening?

Comment: Did you try debugging with the verbose:class JVM option? Should help you figure out which classes are loaded from where.

Comment: Actually, I did try adding `-verbose:class` to command line options, and it shows lots of classes when Glassfish starts, doesn't show anything after it has been loaded, including none of "our" classes. According to this post (http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ss141213/archive/2012/02/23/getting-verbose-class-loading-output-glassfish), this should just work. Dunno.

Comment: About the `-verbose-class` not working, I got it: just adding `-verbose:class` to the `java` command line in `bin/startserv` must add it just for some bootstrap code, which, I guess, runs another JVM. So instead, adding `<jvm-options>-verbose:class</jvm-options>` to `domains/domain1/config/domain.xml` does the job and I now see tons of our classes being loaded. Good.

Comment: Now, the exception says `Could not initialize class org.orbeon.oxf.resources.handler.HTTPURLConnection`, but in the log I just see `Loaded org.orbeon.oxf.resources.handler.HTTPURLConnection$1 from file:/…/orbeon/WEB-INF/lib/orbeon.jar`, and no error. Not sure what to make of this. You have any guess of what could go wrong?

Comment: OK, figured it out: the `NoClassDefFoundError` put me on the wrong track, and the issue was due to an exception that happened earlier in the class static initializer. (I also answered my own question below to mention this.) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

GF delegation model always delegates java.* and javax.* up the classloader chain.

Comment: I am fine with GlassFish always loading `java.*` and `javax.*` classes with its own class loader. I am not trying to provide my own implementation of `java.net.URL`. Instead, I am passing to the `java.net.URL` constructor an instance of my subclass of `URLStreamHandler`. Then, when methods of my URL stream handler are called by `java.net.URL`, I expect other classes it depends on to be found if they are in the in the web app. (And this is something that works with all the other application servers I tried.)

Comment: Since the code I am talking about is open source, you can see it if you're curious: a subclass of `URLStreamHandler` is `HTTPHandler` (https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/java/org/orbeon/oxf/resources/handler/HTTPHandler.java), and an instance is passes to the `java.net.URL` constructor in `URLFactory` (https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/resources/URLFactory.scala).

Comment: The `NoClassDefFoundError` is for `HTTPURLConnection` (https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/java/org/orbeon/oxf/resources/handler/HTTPURLConnection.java), which is used in `HTTPHandler.java`.

Answer (score 1):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` can be caused by the JVM not finding a class, but also to a failure of that [happened earlier in a static initializer](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to.html). The message for the `NoClassDefFoundError` was `Could not initialize class org.orbeon.oxf.resources.handler.HTTPURLConnection`, and there was indeed an error that happened earlier in the static initializer for that class. [Solving](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/installing#TOC-GlassFish-3.1) that error fixed the `NoClassDefFoundError`.